# XSLT Foreach increment not working

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to read an XML and depending on the type of one of the child nodes need to run different logic. As shown in the example below, i need to increment the counter based on Type a or b. This is to identify the relative position of the Item based on Type a or b.

```
  <List>
      <Item>
         <Type>a</Type>
         <value>2</value>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Type>b</Type>
         <value>1</value>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Type>b</Type>
         <value>3</value>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Type>a</Type>
         <value>4</value>
      </Item>
    </List>
```

I'm running foreach loop on Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
<JSON xmlns="">
{
<xsl:variable name="counter" select="0" />
<xsl:for-each select="List/Item">
<xsl:if test="Type='a'">
  <xsl:value-of select="$counter"></xsl:value-of>
  <xsl:variable name="counter" select="$counter + 1" />
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
}
</JSON>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is
0
0

Comment: XSLT is a pure functional language.  There are no "variables", you can't do `$counter = $counter+1`.  If you would like help, please post complete sample input and desired XML output.

Comment: Thanks Jim for letting me know. I did provide the complete sample input i created. I tried using the group-by logic which made it work.

Answer (score 1):

If - as it seems - you only want to number the `Item`s whose `Type` is `"a"`, why can't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/List">
    <JSON>
        <xsl:text>&#10;{&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="Item[Type='a']">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:text>--&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>}&#10;</xsl:text>
    </JSON>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using group-by logic within foreach to get the relative position instead of depending on counter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
<JSON xmlns="">
{
<xsl:variable name="counter" select="0" />
<xsl:for-each-group select="List/Item" group-by="Type='a'">
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
<xsl:if test="current-grouping-key() = true()">
     <xsl:value-of select="position()"></xsl:value-of>--
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each-group>
}
</JSON>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
{
1--
2--
3--    
}
```

Comment: The result is not what you claim it is: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHGs. 
Also, your question is tagged XSLT 1.0, but `xsl:for-each-group` is only available in XSLT 2.0.